# css file mime type when using google docs as static site hosting

Tags: css, google-docs

I tried to use google docs as static site hosting as described here: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en. But browser fails to apply css files. I see warning in chrome developer console : Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain : my_css_filename.css . I guess because of this browser fails to apply css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I created text file, and when renamed it to css extension (in drive web interface). When I created css file on my computer with notepad and uploaded to google, everything began to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue one month ago.

**Solution**

I think you have the following:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_css_filename.css">
```

You only need to had a /

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/my_css_filename.css">
```

Comment: css is loaded, but not applied, so path is not an issue.